# Placing banner ad on bottom of parent with fragments Android

Tags: android, admob, fragment, banner

I'm making an android app but having trouble with positioning a banner.

I have an Activity acting as a container for fragments. I basically want a Scroll View for the root, then the fragment, and an ad on the very bottom.

Here is my XML.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_container"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxx"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here's how the layout looks like

[image]

Basically, the ad is placed directly below the fragment container and it isn't attaching to the viewport's bottom.

I want it to attach to the bottom, then have the scroll view scroll both the fragment + ad together.

This is the only way I could get the ad to appear on the bottom (in short terms):

```
<Constraint layout>
       <Scroll View>
          <Fragment container>
<Ad constraining to parent bottom>
```

However, with this method, the scroll view would only scroll the fragment and doesn't include the ad, meaning you'll get the ad overlapping the fragment content sometimes.

So I think the scroll view must be the root view. However, I'm having trouble managing the child to have the ad appear on the scroll view's bottom, instead of the children's bottom edge.

Comment: Can you use relative layout?

Comment: @Karan - replacing the constraint layout containing the fragment container + ad with a relative layout yields the same results.

Comment: I can add answer of that using relative layout if you want @SmallGrammer

Comment: That would be good for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greets by Nice! Can you try it with RelativeLayout ;)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />


        </ScrollView>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxx"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/> <!--just add this line-->

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way using relative layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />


        </ScrollView>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxx"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/> <!--just add this line-->

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I appreciate your efforts :) that's why up vote it!!

Comment: LOL! Better Luck Next Time ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/adView2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" />


        </ScrollView>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxx"
            ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml with below code

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxx" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Please check below image It's same as you want

[image]

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: @SmallGrammer Are you try this?